# Trouble linking .lib files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, static-libraries

I am currently trying to link three lib files into a C++ project that will read incoming information from a USB port. but after following the steps to add the dmgr.lib and dstm.lib files I am receiving the following errors:

```
Error   6   error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals   c:\users\austi_000\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\USBTest\Debug\USBTest.exe
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DmgrClose referenced in function "void __cdecl ErrorExit(void)" (?ErrorExit@@YAXXZ)    c:\Users\austi_000\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\USBTest\USBTest\DstmDemo.obj
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DmgrOpen referenced in function _main  c:\Users\austi_000\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\USBTest\USBTest\DstmDemo.obj
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DstmDisable referenced in function "void __cdecl ErrorExit(void)" (?ErrorExit@@YAXXZ)  c:\Users\austi_000\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\USBTest\USBTest\DstmDemo.obj
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DstmEnable referenced in function _main    c:\Users\austi_000\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\USBTest\USBTest\DstmDemo.obj
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DstmIO referenced in function _main    c:\Users\austi_000\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\USBTest\USBTest\DstmDemo.obj
```

To add the files I did `Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General`
Then I added `$(DSTM)\lib\x64_win64_vc11_md;$(DMGR)\lib\x64_win64_vc11_md;$(DPCDECL)\lib\x64_win64_vc11_md` to the `Additional Library Directories`.

Next I added `dstm.lib;dmgr.lib;` to `Linker -> Input`.

Next I added `C:\Users\austi_000\Downloads\digilent.adept.sdk_v2.3.1\digilent.adept.sdk_v2.3.1\lib64;C:\Users\austi_000\Downloads\digilent.adept.sdk_v2.3.1\digilent.adept.sdk_v2.3.1\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)` to `C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories`.

Finally I added `C:\Users\austi_000\Downloads\digilent.adept.sdk_v2.3.1\digilent.adept.sdk_v2.3.1\lib64;$(IncludePath)` in `VC++ Directories -> Include Directories` and `C:\Users\austi_000\Downloads\digilent.adept.sdk_v2.3.1\digilent.adept.sdk_v2.3.1\lib64;$(LibraryPath)` in `VC++ Directories -> Library Directories`.

Any clue what's wrong?

Comment: Just double checking: you've defined the environmental variables DSTM, DMGR and DPCDECL? There's a dialog somewhere in VS2012 where you can check the values of all environmental variables. Also, you can get more info about the linking process by adding /VEBOSE:LIB to the additional linker options. This shows what libraries are linked in the output window and often gives hints as to what's wrong.

Comment: @Ralf I'm not sure if I've defined the environmental variables. Where exactly do I add `/VEBOSE:LIB` in the linker info?

Comment: The environmental variables need to be defined in Windows: Control Panel\System and Security\System->Advanced System Settings->Environmental Variables. Alternatively, instead of $(DSTM), use the actual path to the DSTM folder, e.g. C:\xxxx\DSTM, etc. Note that if you change the env vars in Windows, you need to restart the IDE for the changes to take effect.

Comment: /VERBOSE:LIB goes under Project properties->Linker->Command Line->Additional Options

Comment: For the C:\xxxx\DSTM part, do you mean the folder containing the dstm.lib or C:\xxxx\DSTM.lib file itself?

Comment: The folder: this is under the "Additional Library Directories" in your post. That's the only place where I see you're using env variables such as $(DSTM).

Comment: You simply forgot to add a required .lib.  There's a good candidate visible in the question, you mention needing `dpcdecl.lib` but you didn't tell the linker about it.  If that doesn't help then contact the owner of these libraries for support, he'll know what specific .lib contains those missing symbols.

Comment: @Ralf I changed the `$(DSTM)\lib\x64_win64_vc11_md;$(DMGR)\lib\x64_win64_vc11_md;$(DPCDECL)\lib\x64_win64_vc11_md` to `C:\Users\austi_000\Downloads\digilent.adept.sdk_v2.3.1\digilent.adept.sdk_v2.3.1\lib64;` in "Additional Library Directories" (they're all in the same folder). Is that what you meant?

Comment: @HansPassant I changed the question to reflect this but `dcdecl.lib` does not exist, just a header for it

Comment: @Ralf Also, when I place /VERBOSE:LIB in Additional Options it doesn't have any dialog, it just closes the window. Is there a special trick to it? Or does windows 8 negatively affect the functionality of Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: /VERBOSE:LIB merely adds more output in the standard VS output window. What should occur is that you should see when dstm.lib and dmgr.lib are added, and from where. I would assume that those lib files contain the missing symbols. However as Hans Passant indicated, it could also be another missing lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdsk6as6.aspx

To set this linker option in the Visual Studio development environment
Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see Setting Visual C++ Project Properties.
Expand the Linker folder.
Select the Command Line property page.
Add the option to the Additional Options box.